# Retrieve the values of an attribute from a table in webpage using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

How can I retrieve the entire column/attribute values from a table which exists in a webpage using robot framework?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: ${table}=  Get Text  locator    which retrieves the entire table

Comment: The answer really depends on the structure of the html; add that, plus - any code attempts you have so far.